# Resetting validation after calling setLocale in aureliajs

Tags: javascript, aurelia

The scenario is as follows: I have a form that is displaying validation messages when a given field is not valid. Now when I change aureliajs locale settings, I'd like the validation messages to be rerendered in the chosen language. Is there a way to do it automatically? Am I missing something here?

This is how I set a new locale:

```
setLang(activeLanguage) {
    this.i18n.setLocale(activeLanguage);
}
```

And this is how I render validation messages:

```
<div class="control-group col-md-9 col-xs-12" validation-errors.bind="form.nameErrors">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="${'restaurantName' & t}" value.bind="form.model.name & validate" />
    <span class="help-block" repeat.for="errorInfo of form.nameErrors">${errorInfo.error.message}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could found something in the aurelia docs here => [Integrating with Aurelia-I18N](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics/12)

An other idea is to use the withMessage('term') or withMessageKey('term') and use the t attribute on the error span to auto translate the term into your error message. (I have not tried)